# Negative bayes factor and how to fix it

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, brms

I am currently trying to calculate bayes factor for eye tracking study. I created linear mixed-effect model and found best random factor structure using buildmer. On there, p value for the main effect is significant (<2e-16). When I insert the best fitting model from buildmer into brm() function and insert that brm model to hypothesis() function to calculate bayes factor, I am getting an extremely big negative value (which is contradictory to p value).

I checked all variables and contrasts (since there are only 2 conditions, so we are assigning -0.5 or 0.5) to see if they are correct and appropriately set, but they are. I am assuming the reason why such contradiction is happening is because from condition -0.5 to 0.5, there should be a positive correlation (which means condition -0.5 is numerically lower than condition 0.5) but on linear mixed-effect model, it says the correlation of main effect is negative. But I do not know why this is happening nor how to fix it.

Do you mind giving insights on why this is happening and what can I do to solve this? If you have any questions, please ask and I will respond asap.

Comment: Bayes Factors depend on the priors, which you didn't discuss here at all. I recommend reading the chapter on Bayes Factors in this textbook and seeing if the approach there helps fix your issue: https://vasishth.github.io/bayescogsci/book/

Comment: Guesses: 1. since p so small, overflow or under flow error in Bayes factor computation. 2. you’re computing log B_01, log of Bayes factor for null